# Why is pre-commit using git:// rather than https:// (as per .pre-commit-config.yaml)

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm looking to use pre-commit to perform `terraform validate` before I commit a change.

My .pre-commit-config.yaml is like this:

```
https://github.com/antonbabenko/pre-commit-terraform# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files
-   repo: https://github.com/antonbabenko/pre-commit-terraform
    rev: 1.74.1
    hooks:
    -   id: terraform_validate
```

I get the following error on a `git commit` command:

```
[INFO] Initializing environment for git://github.com/antonbabenko/pre-commit-terraform. 
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/usr/lib/git-core/git', 'fetch', 'origin', '--tags')   
return code: 128   
expected return code: 0   
stdout: (none)   
stderr:
        fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
        github.com[0: 140.82.113.3]: errno=Connection timed out 
Check the log at /home/me/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

why is it trying to go to **git**://github.com/antonbabenko/pre-commit-terraform?

I get the same error for `pre-commit autoupdate`.

pre-commit version is: 2.19.0

Edit: including my ~/.gitconfig

```
[user]
        email = <my_email_address>
        name = Matthew Thompson
```

```
git config --show-origin --list 

file:/home/matthew/.gitconfig   user.email=<my_email_address>
file:/home/matthew/.gitconfig   user.name=Matthew Thompson
```

Comment: show your `~/.gitconfig`? you probably have a bad `insteadOf` somewhere

Comment: thanks @AnthonySottile - I was hoping you'd see this :) - I've added the gitconfig... unfortunately no insteadof there.... could there be another config location for this config?

Comment: how about `git config --show-origin --list` ?

Comment: that comes back the same...

Comment: can you `grep repo .pre-commit-config.yaml` ? -- also `env | grep GIT` ?  and maybe show the error log file as well?

Comment: bingo, was in the .pre-commit-config.yaml at the root of the folder

Comment: I have just checked the history and someone has tried pre-commit on the project before - it is old config file that appears to have been activated when I installed pre-commit locally.... thanks for your help. I hadn't realized a local file would take precedence over my user config